# making a simple countdown clock in php with variable end time

Tags: php, date

trying to make a simple countdown timer in PHP based on some input from a database which will tweak the end time slightly (with a constant base). However it seems to keep throwing up really strange numbers in the countdowns. I pretty much guarantee my math is wrong somewhere.

**PHP**

```
$timeUntil = 10; // for tweaking time remaining (days), this will be dynamic in actual program but will always be an integer
$timeStamp = 1445438099; // timestamp of roughly 2 months in the future
    $zUnixDays = $timeUntil * 86400; // converting integer (days) into seconds
    $zFinalTime = $timeStamp - $zUnixDays; //tweaking the constant time with the variable time
    $remaining = $zFinalTime - time(); // seconds remaining from the future time til now 
    $seconds_remaining = $remaining%60;
    $minutes_remaining = floor(($remaining%3600)/60);
    $hours_remaining = floor(($remaining%86400)/3600);
    $days_remaining = floor(($remaining%2592000)/86400);
    $zTimeCombined = array($days_remaining, $hours_remaining, $minutes_remaining, $seconds_remaining);
    echo json_encode($zTimeCombined);
```

**JS**

```
var result = JSON.parse(results);
                var zDays = result[0];
                var zHours = result[1];
                var zMinutes = result[2];
                var zSeconds = result[3];
```

this should return around 50 days remaining (2 months - 10 days.. very rough) but instead returns 21 days. Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use DateTime instead, it's much easier:

```
$future = new DateTime();
$future->setTimestamp(1445438099); // passing in to constructor directly is wonky
$start = $future->sub(new DateInterval('P10D'));
$diff = $start->diff(new DateTime());
$interval = $diff->format('%y:%m:%d:%h:%i:%s');
// 0:1:20:23:29:45
list($year, $month, $day, $hour, $minute, $second) = explode(':', $interval);
```

Comment: any chance you could break this down a bit? Ive never used this method before, be good to get a view of how it works

Comment: it just replicates your logic. create a new date(), set its value. calculate "10 days ago". then calculate the difference between this "10 days ago" and "now", then format that difference into a bunch of years/months/days/etc...

Comment: the only bit i can see a problem with is the 'P10D' bit when subtracting the days. I would need some way to replace this with a variable, is there an easy way to do this? At the moment ive got around it by passing the variable through to JS by attaching it to the end of an array with the rest of the date numbers and then just adding it with JS. Its not very elegant though

Comment: (as you probably guessed, im not very experienced with PHP!)

Comment: it's just a string. `'P' . $days . 'D'`

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$daysToFuture = 10;

// 10 Days in Future
$futureTs = mktime(0,0,0,date("n"),date("j")+$daysToFuture,date("Y"));

// remaining till now ...
$remaining = $futureTs-time();

// in Days
$days_remaining = date("d",$remaining);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($days_remaining); echo "</pre>";

// in hours
$hours_remaining = date("H",$remaining);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($hours_remaining); echo "</pre>";

// in minutes
$minutes_remaining = date("i",$remaining);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($minutes_remaining); echo "</pre>";

// in seconds
$seconds_remaining = date("s",$remaining);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($seconds_remaining); echo "</pre>";

// Array
$zTimeCombined = array($days_remaining, $hours_remaining, $minutes_remaining, $seconds_remaining);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($zTimeCombined); echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: This doesnt seem to include the time constant i require in the program

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) objects

```
$dateTime = new DateTime();
$dateTime->setTimestamp(1445438099);

$timeInTheFuture = $dateTime->modify('-10 days');

$dateInterval = $timeInTheFuture->diff(new DateTime());

echo json_encode(explode(' ', $dateInterval->format('%d %h %i %s')));
```

Comment: this looks interesting, ive not come accross this before, could you break down the method a bit so i can understand what is happening?

Comment: all this returns is [d,h, i, s]

Comment: I've updated my answer.. I will add some comments to better understand how it works.. I'm not on my pc right now

Comment: cheers, main thing im trying to do now is replace the - 10 days with a variable. Another option is i could pass the days, hours, mins, seconds back along with this variable then just add it on using javascript on the client side